# Search Bar in a Flyout Menu Page in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

How can i add a Search bar in a Flyout menu bar in MAUI? I`ve added a Flyout menu:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="AGROWORKS.MOBILE.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AGROWORKS.MOBILE"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Parsel ya da Kişi Arayın"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
</Shell>
```

Now I`m trying to figure out how to implement a search bar in it.

Comment: I would look into [Titleview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-7.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) you can set the navigation bar content with it

Comment: Have you tried add a search bar in flyout header?

Comment: it didn`t work. So i ve made page for the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a search bar, create a SearchBar object and set its Placeholder property to text that instructs the user to enter a search term.

```
<SearchBar Placeholder="Search items..." />
```

https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/UserInterface/ControlGallery/ControlGallery/Views/XAML/SearchBarDemoPage.xaml

Comment: If you can add how it will be included in a Shell menu it would be perfect :)

Comment: And what's supposed to happen after the user entered something?

Comment: its gonna take the neccesarry items from the database and than it will be a search bar for the saved files.

Comment: By using the binding context object in the search bar you can use entity framework by connection to database and query for data object for it to display. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli